# How to convert String^ to String in C++ CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Whenever I try to directly assign a String variable to another String variable I get error found no suitable conversation.
So is there a way to convert String^ pointer to a non-pointer struct String ?

I want :

```
System::String a = System::String('X',256);
```

I don't want :

```
System::String^ a = %System::String('X',256);
```

Comment: System::String is an immutable reference type.  You don't get to change that, you must use the hat.  If you don't like the syntax then just don't use C++/CLI, both C# and VB.NET make no distinction between value and reference types in their syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not, because as Hans pointed out in a comment, `System::String` is immutable.  You cannot assign it.  You can only associate a handle with an entirely new `System::String` object.

BTW

```
System::String^ a = %System::String('X',256);
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
System::String^ a = gcnew System::String('X',256);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `System::String a('X', 256);`.

Comment: Thanks but this is not conversion, it was just an example. What if I want assign `System::String a` to `System::String b` ?

Comment: Then why don't you use `b = a`?

Comment: That throw error `C3149: 'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'`